# How to capture screenshot of full children in widgets under scrollview

Tags: flutter

I tried using the lib `widgets_to_image` but it only captures what is currently on the screen and cannot capture full widgets. How can I make a screenshot with full children widgets?

Here is a sample widget:

```
SingleChildScrollView(
  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
  child: SingleChildScrollView(
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Row(
          children: [
            Container(
              color: Colors.red,
              width: width,
              height: height,
            ),
            Container(
              color: Colors.green,
              width: width,
              height: height,
            ),
          ],
        ),
        Row(
          children: [
            Container(
              color: Colors.yellowAccent,
              width: width,
              height: height,
            ),
            Container(
              color: Colors.purple,
              width: width,
              height: height,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Use screenshot package which have this method to capture long widgets.
https://pub.dev/packages/screenshot#capturing-a-list-widget

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this [screenshot](https://pub.dev/packages/screenshot) package